# RedirectToAction shows 404 in page, but still redirects

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a Controller method with the following code:

```
ClearAuthenticationCookies();
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(EmailAddress, false);

RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

var responseObject = new responseObject
{
    responseCode = "2",
    responseMessage = "No"
};
return Json(new {responseObject = responseObject});
```

This is executed from another website via ajax, but doesn't show the proper url in the browser.  If I login directly, it works:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:51437/UserAccount/SignOn2",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonData,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(result) {
        },
        error: function(result) {
        }
    });
```

I also have to click my link twice before it actually logs me in, but the page is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller signature should been `public RedirectResult SignOn(...)` and `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` is the object that you should return from your controller. Don't return any `JsonResult` after this.

**UPDATE:**
You can return one response over one request.
To achieve what you want, you have two options. First: return json result, then when client receive json result and verify it you can send another request to server and and than redirect to another page. Or you can redirect from the client, using `window.location.replace` to change current page via js. Furthemore, you can prepare link on the server to achieve all .net routes advantage and include it to the json result and than make something like this:

```
$.ajax {
  ..
  ..
  ..
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data.message_for_user);
    window.location.replace(data.url_to_redirect);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this when I get a chance, but what if I want to redirect the user, but also return a JsonResult. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks, I went with this, but instead when I return a success, I open a window with the url instead of doing a replace. My only concern is what happens with popup blockers?

Comment: don't care until you'll get a problem

Comment: It's OK, I found a way to circumvent the popup blockers.

Comment: Don't forget to close all other questions, I answer on them too